# Flask app on Elasticbeanstalk - "Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat"

Tags: flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have built an application using Flask called "app.py". It runs locally when I use "flask run". However, when I upload it to AWS Elasticbeanstalk, the environment status changes to "Severe" and in the logs I get the error message "Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat".

I solved the issue, and have posted the solution below in case it is helpful to others.

Answer (score 2):

The application runs locally because I previously ran the command "export FLASK_APP=app.py" to modify the environment variable. This informs Flask my application is called "app.py". However, on Elasticbeanstalk the default application name is "application.py". You can see this by going to the AWS Console > Elasticbeanstalk > Your environment > Configuration > Software > Modify > Container Options > WSGI Path.

[image: AWS Elasticbeanstalk Configuration]

There are therefore 2 solutions.

1. Rename your application file from "app.py" to "application.py" to conform to the default WSGI Path on AWS Elasticbeanstal.
2. Change the WSGI Path environment variable on AWS Elasticbeanstalk to "app.py" to match the name of your application file. This can be done in one of two ways. First, via the AWS Console > Elasticbeanstalk > Your environment > Configuration > Software > Modify > Container Options > Change the WSGI Path variable > Apply. And second, using the Elasticbeanstalk Command Line Interface (EB CLI) with the command "eb config" > Scroll down to the heading aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python: > Modify WSGIPath > Save changes.

If you are still receiving this error, also check that your application file is in the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

Milos answer works. I wanted to add that if your Flask app is created inside an `__init__.py` then you have to specify the packagename as well.
For example, the [Flaskr](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/factory/) application would have a WSGI Path of "`flaskr/__init__.py`"